# Why Contains with Entity Framework slows down performance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
predicates.Add(PredicateBuilder.Create<Ad>(a => options.Ids.Contains(a.Model.Id)));
```

It generates the `IN` SQL statement and takes 0.2962969 seconds to run.

If I replace the above code with:

```
foreach (var id in options.Ids)
{
    predicates.Add(PredicateBuilder.Create<Ad>(a => a.Model.Id == id));
}
```

It also generates the same `IN` SQL statement but now it takes 0.0820531 seconds to run.

Both SQL statements takes basically the same time to run on the SQL server.

Comment: You don't actually need `PredicateBuilder`, did you measure the performance using `predicates.Add(a => options.Ids.Contains(a.Model.Id))`?

Comment: this is much more complex than this, there is a lot of of conditions and stuff. That's why I use a predicate builders. But I isolated this to test and the numbers I posted increases just by adding the Contains to the predicates

Comment: Can you show your full code? Without more context we won't know whether the bottleneck is in the SQL generated or in the predicates

Comment: What version of entity framework are you running?

Comment: Entity Framework 6.1.2. @rexcfnghk Full source code is too long, the only relevant part is this, after this predicates list is filled, I do a query = query.Where(predicate); where predicate is a returned as predicates.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.Or)